# Conditional value for HTML input and textarea elements (if IE8/IE9)

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, textarea

The placeholder property of HTML's `input` and `textarea` elements is terrific, but it doesn't work with IE8 or IE9. So, I'm looking for a way to set the value property only when the user is browsing from IE8 or IE9.

I've tried this sort of thing:

```
<textarea name="comment" placeholder="Message"><!--[if lte IE 9]>Message<![endif]-->
</textarea>
```

But the whole "…!--[if lte IE 9]>…" string is outputted in the textarea regardless of the browser. (I'm not looking to recreate the placeholder effect in IE8/9, just set the value.)

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this type of combination instead:

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]><textarea name="comment">Message</textarea><![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]> --><textarea name="comment" placeholder="Message"></textarea><!-- <![endif]-->
```

Only one of them will appear in either case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that looks great. I'm wondering though what happens if a user arrived from IE 10. Wouldn't both conditions then be false?

Comment: No, ie 10 and newer do not use the conditional comments, so you are fine. Only IE5.5-9 use the 'if not ie' thing.

Comment: Ah, OK, so [if !IE] effectively means [if !IE5.5-9]. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: So is there any point in the `lte IE 9` part, wouldn't `if IE` suffice?

Comment: You are right again! I usually do the lte ie9 so it is easy to read, but both are equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than writing extra markup each time you want to use a placeholder, it's far better to perform a feature-detection test and apply a polyfill when the browser doesn't natively support the attribute/property. Tests for these types of features aren't that difficult to author either:

```js
"placeholder" in document.createElement("textarea");
```

If this expression evaluates to `true` you have no additional work to perform — the browser supports the attribute. If the expression evaluates to `false`, you know that you need to extend a prototype to add support, or load a polyfill that does this for you.

A cursory search on the web reveals [Placeholder.js](http://jamesallardice.github.io/Placeholders.js/), which should require nothing more than a script reference.

```html
<textarea placeholder="That's it, done."></textarea>
<script src="assets/js/placeholders.min.js"></script>
```

From there it appears you can author more granular instruction over which types of scenarios should be supported, but this isn't necessary for basic support.